# Python2.7.6でOpenCV Errorが発生します

Tags: python, opencv, python2

OpenCVでデータの読み込みを読み込みます。しかし、画像を28×28サイズに圧縮する際に次のエラーが出てしまいました。

**エラー内容**

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0) in resize, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 1824
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 136, in <module>
    img = cv2.resize(img, (28,28))
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 1824:
error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0 in function resize
```

**コード（長文のためエラーが出る付近のみ抜粋）**

```
conding:utf-8
import cv2
（中略）
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ファイルを開く
    f = open(FLAGS.train, 'r')  # train.txt
    train_image = []
    train_label = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        l = line.split()
        img = cv2.imread(l[0])
        **img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28))** ←エラー発生部位
        train_image.append(img.flatten().astype(np.float32)/255.0)
        tmp = np.zeros(NUM_CLASSES)
        tmp[int(l[1])] = 1
        train_label.append(tmp)
    train_image = np.asarray(train_image)
    train_label = np.asarray(train_label)
    train_len = len(train_image)
    f.close()
```

おそらくですが、データが途上で受け渡せていない恐れがあると思います。
どのような原因が考えられるでしょうか。
どなたかわかる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

開発環境
Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS
Python 2.7.6
OpenCV 2.4.8

Comment: PythonのOpenCVはCライブラリのラッパーなので、エラーの原因を探るのはかなり辛いです。ありがちなのは画像のカラーモード。グレースケールだと動いたりすることもあります。

Comment: `cv2.imread`で読み込もうとしているファイル名(`l[0]`)について、(1)ファイルが存在しているか？(2)読み込み権限があるか？(3)画像ファイルフォーマットは何か？を確認してください。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi さん
アドバイスありがとうございます。カラーモードをグレースケールに変えましたが、
残念ながらエラーは消えませんでした。かなり原因を追究するには厳しいエラー
みたいですね。

Comment: エラーは「resizeする対象の画像(変数 img)の大きさは0より大きくなくちゃダメじゃん！」という指摘ですから、img = cv2.imread(l[0])の"l[0]"から画像を読み込めていないのが直接の原因です。
エラー発生場所の前に、print(f)、print(l)、print(l[0])の３行を追加して実行すると、状況が把握できるのではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

エラーメッセージに

```
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 1824:
error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0 in function resize
```

とあるので，手元にある OpenCV 2.4.9 のソースで確認してみると，

```
CV_Assert( ssize.area() > 0 );
```

で失敗しているようです．ssize は入力画像 img のサイズ，
ssize.area() はその面積なので，**imread() に失敗して img

のサイズが０になっている**と思われます．

imread() は失敗してもエラーを報告せず，サイズ０の画像を
返すだけなので，(この場合に限らず) imread() が返した
画像のサイズが０でないかチェックするようにしてください．

imread() が失敗する原因としては，画像ファイルがオープン
できない，モード指定の誤りなどがありますが，この場合は
オープンの失敗だと思われます．**l[0] は期待どおりの値に

なってますか？**

Python は使ったことがない のでわかりませんが，
(C/C++ と同様に) Python でも **errno** が使えるようなので，
これを調べればオープンに失敗した原因はわかるはずです．

errno — 標準の errno システムシンボル(原文)
http://docs.python.jp/2/library/errno.html