# files = os.listdir('./data/' + d)でのエラーについて

Tags: python, tensorflow

[[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]][1
]
↑print(omg)の結果
画像の独自のデータセットを読み込もうとしています。
下記のコードの`img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))`でエラーがでました。
`data` というディレクトリの下にa,b,c,d,e,fというディレクトリがあってそのディレクトリに画像のファイルが大量に入っています。ファイルの拡張子はpngやjpegです。
データセットの読み込みを教えていただければありがたいです。

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
NUM_CLASSES = 6 #分類するクラス数
IMG_SIZE = 28

#画像のあるディレクトリ
train_img_dirs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

#学習画像データ
train_image = []
#学習データのラベル
train_label = []
for i, d in enumerate(train_img_dirs):
 # ./data/以下の各ディレクトリ内のファイル名取得
files = os.listdir('Users/name/desktop/zissou/data/' + d)
for f in files:
    # 画像読み込み
    img = cv2.imread('Users/name/desktop/zissou/data/' + d + '/' + f)
    # 1辺がIMG_SIZEの正方形にリサイズ
    img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    # 1列にして
    img = img.flatten().astype(np.float32)/255.0
    train_image.append(img)

    # one_hot_vectorを作りラベルとして追加
    tmp = np.zeros(NUM_CLASSES)
    tmp[i] = 1
    train_label.append(tmp)

# numpy配列に変換
train_image = np.asarray(train_image)
train_label = np.asarray(train_label)
```

エラー内容

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-4ca319834c1e> in <module>()
      6         img = cv2.imread('/Users/tadashintaro/desktop/zissou/data/' + d + '/' + f)
      7         # 1辺がIMG_SIZEの正方形にリサイズ
----> 8         img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
      9         # 1列にして
     10         img = img.flatten().astype(np.float32)/255.0

error: /Users/jenkins/miniconda/1/x64/conda-     bld/conda_1486587097465/work/opencv-    3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3229: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0    in function resize**
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参照：http://qiita.com/domkade/items/fc9903c2119fdfa9a234

Comment: (ソースのコピペをミスってるようですがそれはさておき) そのプログラムは「デスクトップ」フォルダで実行していますか。相対パスは(故意に使う場合は除き)使わないか、最初に実行ディレクトリを絶対パスで指定するべきです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。このプログラムはデスクトップでは実行していなく、デスクトップのフォルダの中のzissouというフォルダの中で実行しています。相対パスを絶対パスに変えるとここではエラーは出ませんでした。が今度は　**#1辺がIMG_SIZEの正方形にリサイズimg = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))**　でエラーが出てしまいました。

Comment: a 〜 f ディレクトリに入っているファイルは画像ファイルだけなのでしょうか？例えばテキストファイルなどが混じっていないでしょうか？

Comment: @user23690 エラーメッセージで検索してみてください。たとえばこのスタック・オーバーフロー上にも[類似の質問が存在します。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/30107/19110)

Comment: 画像だけだと思います。拡張子は.png, jpeg, jpgだけでした。ありがとうございます。検索してみます。

Comment: 空(0バイト)の画像ファイルが存在するため、その画像を処理する際にエラーが起きている。もしくは、画像ファイルの読み込みに失敗しているのではないかと思われます。imreadで読み込んだ画像データ(変数img)のサイズをログに書き出すようにすると問題の箇所が明らかになると思いますよ。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。print(img)をfor ループ内でしたところNone
[[[ 70 115  59]
  [ 70 115  59]
  [ 70 115  59]
  ..., 
  [ 75 121  62]
  [ 86 125  69]
 。。。のように出ましたNoneというのが問題でしょうか？また[  0 199 238]のような出力もあります。

Comment: ファイル名(変数 `f`)も表示する様にすると問題のあるファイルがどれなのか分かるかと思いますよ。

Comment: このNone[[[70 115 59] [70 115 59] [70 115 59]~というのは何を指しているんでしょうか？これがどうなっていたら問題のあるファイルだとわかりますか？初心者です。すいませんが教えてもらえるとありがたいです。

Comment: Fumuさんやmetropolisさんが指摘しているように、画像ファイルがおかしい可能性がありますね。エラーを出すファイル名とその原因（ファイルが壊れているなど）をわかるには、resizeする前に、cv2.imshow("Before resizing image",img)で画像ファイルをチェックすることをお勧めします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

さてコメント欄で指摘されているように類似の質問があるとおり，とりあえず今のところ話題になっているメッセージからは読み込もうとしているファイルの中に空のものがあるのではないかというのが一番怪しいということにしましょう．というわけで

#### Q. フォルダ下にたくさんの画像ファイルらしきものがあるとき，その中から空のものを見つけるにはどうすればよいか．

多分いちばん簡単なのは， Linux 上でしたら [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Size) のようなコマンドを使うことですけれども，せっかくなので今あるコードをできるだけ再利用してみましょう．
（ところで， 質問する前に余分なコードはできるだけ省くようにすべきです．そうして初めて問題の所在が分かって正しいググり方も分かるということがあります．今回なら tensorflow 周りは一切要りませんし，`resize` を試みて困ってるわけですからそれ以降の処理も余分です）

ファイルごとに処理をしているところでこういう感じにできたら良さそうですね．

```
for f in files:
    # 画像読み込み
    img = cv2.imread('Users/name/desktop/zissou/data/' + d + '/' + f)
    # 空ファイルがあったら教えてもらう
    if is_empty(img):
        print("{} っていうディレクトリの{}っていうファイルが怪しい!".format(d,f))
```

では空ファイルをどうみつけていくか．その前に空ファイルがどう扱われるか実験してみましょう． ターミナル（Bash を想定しています）で `$ touch empty.jpg` などで空のファイルを作っておいて

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2

empty = cv2.imread('./empty.jpg')
print(empty)   # None
cv2.resize(empty, (3,3)) # OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0) in resize, file /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 3483
```

いい感じにそれっぽいエラーがでること，空ファイルを読むと `None` が返されていることがわかります(ファイル名を間違えていても同様に `None` が返ってきます)．というわけで

```
if img is None:
```

などで判定を入れてみるのが良いだろうと思います．

以下余談．

---

#### そもそも不明なエラーが出てるけど原因を探りたい

ときというのは色々あると思いますが，エラーメッセージで検索する他に，今回でしたら例えばどのファイルで詰まってるのを知りたいとしましょう．僕ならこうします：

```
for f in files:
    # 画像読み込み
    img = cv2.imread('Users/name/desktop/zissou/data/' + d + '/' + f)
    try:
        img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    except Exception as e:
        # うまく行かないときは報告
        print(e)
        print("{} っていうディレクトリの{}っていうファイルが怪しい!".format(d,f))
```

書捨て的なトライアルができるのはスクリプト言語の気軽なところなので，色々試してみるといいです．

Comment: とても分かりやすい回答で助かりました。ありがとうございます。