# Deep MNIST for Expertsを参考しながら、オリジナルの色のついた画像を六個のクラスに分類できるようにするには

Tags: python, tensorflow, 機械学習

下記のコードはオリジナルの画像データセットをTensorFlowのチュートリアルDeep MNIST for Expertsを参考しながら、色のついた画像を六個のクラスに分類できるようにしたかったもですが

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50, 784) for Tensor 'Placeholder_15:0', which has shape '(?, 2352)'
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。
チュートリアルと違って分類するクラスの数や色のついた画像といったところを変えようとは思っているんですがうまくいきません。

教えてもらえればありがたいです。

参照：[files = os.listdir('./data/' + d)でのエラーについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37709/files-os-listdir-data-d%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)

環境：os　→　macOS10.12.5
     python　→　Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)
     tensorflow →　tensorflow (1.3.0)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
NUM_CLASSES = 6 #分類するクラス数
IMG_SIZE = 28

#画像のあるディレクトリ
train_img_dirs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

#学習画像データ
train_image = []
#学習データのラベル
train_label = []

for i, d in enumerate(train_img_dirs):
     # ./data/以下の各ディレクトリ内のファイル名取得
    files = os.listdir('/Users/name/desktop/zissou/data/' + d)

    for f in files:
        #画像読み込み
        img = cv2.imread('/Users/name/desktop/zissou/data/' + d + '/' + f) 
        try:
            #1辺がIMG_SIZEの正方形にリサイズ
            img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
            #一列にして
            img = img.flatten().astype(np.float32)/255.0
            train_image.append(img)

            #one_hot_vectorを作りラベルとして追加
            tmp = np.zeros(NUM_CLASSES)
            tmp[i] = 1
            train_label.append(tmp)

        except Exception as e:
            #うまくいかないときは報告
            print(e)
            print("{}　ってうディレクトリの{}　っていうファイルが怪しい ターミナルでrmコマンドで削除できるよ".format(d,f))

#numpy配列に変換
train_image = np.asarray(train_image)
train_label = np.asarray(train_label)

print(train_image)

import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
COLOR_CHANNELS = 3 # RGB
IMG_PIXELS = IMG_SIZE * IMG_SIZE * COLOR_CHANNELS # 画像のサイズ*RGB
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, IMG_PIXELS])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, NUM_CLASSES])
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                      strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME') 
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, COLOR_CHANNELS, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, COLOR_CHANNELS])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) +b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
W_fc1 = weight_variable([7*7*64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) +b_fc1)
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, NUM_CLASSES])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([NUM_CLASSES])

y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) +b_fc2)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(20000):
    if i%100==0:
       train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
```

エラー

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-8b9cd3a3500c> in <module>()
13     if i%100==0:
14         train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
---> 15             x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})      
16         print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
17     train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

〜〜〜〜〜〜〜〜


ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50, 784) for Tensor 'Placeholder_15:0', which has shape '(?, 2352)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xの定義は

```
IMG_PIXELS = IMG_SIZE * IMG_SIZE * COLOR_CHANNELS # 画像のサイズ*RGB
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, IMG_PIXELS])
```

となっておりますので、feedで与えるべきデータは(?, 28*28*3)の形である必要があります。

batchをどのように取ってきているのかはご提示のコードからではわかりませんが、
ログから見るに色情報なしのデータ(28*28のみ)がflattenされたものを与えている物と思います。
"このコードに合わせるなら"28*28*3のflattenデータを与えなければ動作しません。

ただし、通常は色情報を含めてまであまりflattenしないと思います。
tf.image APIを用いて[w,h,c]の形で扱うのが良いと思います。
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_png

もしくは入門編としてCifar10のtuterialをお勧めします。
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn#cifar-10_model